ASP.NET Core 8 Web API returns status code 400 for .NET 8 client
This is driving me nuts and I can't figure out what the problem is. I have one project consisting of Web APIs and another project, the client, which calls them. Both projects are built using VS 2022, .NET 8.
This is my authentication function:
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("Authenticate")]
    public async Task<UserLoginResponse> Authenticate(string lr)
    {
        UserLoginResponse resp = new UserLoginResponse { Success = false, ResultMessage = string.Empty, UserToken = "" };
        UserSignIn usi = default;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lr))
        {
            resp.Success = false;
            resp.ResultCodes = LoginResponseCodes.UserNamePasswordRequired;
            resp.UserToken = string.Empty;
            return resp;
        }

        try
        {
            usi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSignIn>(lr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            resp.Success = false;
            resp.ResultCodes = LoginResponseCodes.UserNamePasswordRequired;
            resp.UserToken = string.Empty;
            return resp;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usi.Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(usi.Password))
        {
            resp.Success = false;
            resp.ResultMessage = "Valid User Name (email)/Password Required";
        }
        else
        {
            //resp = await _userService.Authenticate(usi);
            //if(resp == null)
            //{
            //    resp = new UserLoginResponse { Success = false, ResultMessage = "NULL Error", UserToken = "" };
            //}
        }

        return resp;
    }

And here is one of the many client variations I've tried, which all result in a

StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'

Code:
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("Authenticate")]
    public async Task<UserLoginResponse> Authenticate(string lr)
    {
        UserLoginResponse resp = new UserLoginResponse { Success = false, ResultMessage = string.Empty, UserToken = "" };
        UserSignIn usi = default;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lr))
        {
            resp.Success = false;
            resp.ResultCodes = LoginResponseCodes.UserNamePasswordRequired;
            resp.UserToken = string.Empty;
            return resp;
        }

        try
        {
            usi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSignIn>(lr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            resp.Success = false;
            resp.ResultCodes = LoginResponseCodes.UserNamePasswordRequired;
            resp.UserToken = string.Empty;
            return resp;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usi.Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(usi.Password))
        {
            resp.Success = false;
            resp.ResultMessage = "Valid User Name (email)/Password Required";
        }
        else
        {
            //resp = await _userService.Authenticate(usi);
            //if(resp == null)
            //{
            //    resp = new UserLoginResponse { Success = false, ResultMessage = "NULL Error", UserToken = "" };
            //}
        }

        return resp;
    }

There are no errors produced anywhere, at least none I've been able to find.
If I test my API call using the Swagger client, it works fine. It also works fine when I use the following Javascript in an html page.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function CallWebApi() {
        var url = "https://localhost:7598/api/BlueUsers/Authenticate?lr=%7B%22Email%22%3A%22testemail%40gmail.com%22%2C%22Password%22%3A%22hjgtdsrsdes%22%7D";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    CallWebApi();

Could someone please help me with what I'm missing and/or doing incorrectly in my .NET client?
Thank you

Hello, I think the issue is with the parameter that you are not sending correctly the lr as the method POST expected the body to have the param, thus you got 400

If the method works when called from swagger and javascript, then the problem is with the request that is failing, like an invalid header or body. Can you provide the failing request?

use [FromQuery] like     public async Task<UserLoginResponse> Authenticate([FromQuery] string lr)
review this page please https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Looks like you're correct.  Removed the parameter and I'm hitting the function.   I thought I had tried this before but I guess not.  Anyway, sanity restored, Thank you.

You can apply these steps to identify the issue:

Increasing the logging level through an appsettings.json file will allow you to see what the various converters, middleware and controllers are doing, and most importantly it allows you to compare the differences between the call from the AJAX snippet vs. your .NET 8 client.
Like pointed out in the comments, the default binding logic of an ASP.NET Core application will try to bind lr from the body of the request. You are using a query parameter, so adding a [FromQuery] parameter attribute helps the framework determine that the parameter is expected to come from the query part of the request.
In the .NET 8 client code, be sure to check that the query string is properly encoded.


The rep requirement for comments is not an invitation to write an answer with what should have been a comment. This is not an answer, just a collection of debugging tips.

Then please explain how someone who doesn't have enough rep for a comment can ask the author of the question for more details, or fixes to the original question? Simply by reading the question it is obvious that there's pieces of the puzzle missing.
Or is this one of those "impossible to answer" questions?

You don't. You leave it to those with enough rep. Meanwhile, answer what you can and earn the rep you need. Part of what te rep requirement does help you learn the norms of the site Watch and learn.

Speaking of learning, debugging tips like this don't actually answer the question. You're not going to gain the rep you need by doing that.

Thanks for your thoughts. Let's hope that in the future those with more reputation are smart enough to point out the rather obvious issue that this question is missing the entire .NET 8 client-side code so it is complete guesswork on what might be going wrong in there.
